# cxf restful return image

Tags: java, image, rest, cxf

I'm new using CXF and Spring to make RESTful webservices. The project is under maven control.

I have a android app that would like to connect to the server retrieving book information and cover picture via RESTful webservices. Is it possible (and how) RESTful service return an image?

**Project Explorer**

```
Project
--Java Resource
----src/main/java
------library.service
--------IBook.java
--------Book.java
----images
------Cover1.png
------Cover2.png
--JavaResources
--Deployed Resources
----webapp
------WEB-INF
----web-resources
```

**IBook.java interface**

```
@GET
@Path("/book/cover/{name}")
@Produces("image/png")
public Image getImage(@PathParam("name") String name);
```

**Book.java impl**

```
public Image getImage(String name){
    //How should I get cover png from 'images' folder and return it??
}
```

Thanks

Silvester Pang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return your selected image via Response.ok(params...).build()

Change your IBook.java to

```
    @GET
    @Path("/book/cover/{name}")
    @Produces("image/*")
    public Response getImage(@PathParam("name") String name);
```

And your Implementing Interface to this.

```
public Response getImage(String name){
    File file = new File(fileUrl);
    String mediaType = SomeContentTypeMapHere(file)
    return Response.ok(file,mediaType).build()
}
```

**EDIT**

We've used `Response.ok(Object type, String mediaType).build()` to Build and return a Response when our method handler is called. The First parameter is an Object. think it of as the Thing we're going to send when somebody/someones  sends a request on the given url while mediaType is basically the Content type(e.g, "image/png, image/jpg and etc) of what we're going to send.

Remember to match your `@Produces("image/*")` to the content type you are passing on the `ok(Object entity, String mediaType` method.

Comment: I'm not really understand the use of Response. Would you mind to explain a little bit?